# Selenium Java, how to change Webdriver from one Tab to another Tab (second Tab open after first Tab click on a hyper link)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, selenium

First I click hyper link on mailinator email and open new tab and popup in the same window as I added into screenshot image.

Sometime this code work after tab make refresh but same time event not refresh also not working.  I hope sometime driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);  not working properly.

**HTML Code Here:-**

```
<div id="zDeskPasswordConfirm" class="modal fade ng-scope in" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" style="display: block;">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header portal-header">
<button class="close" aria-label="Close" ng-click="close()" data-target="#zDeskSignup" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
<div>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
<form id="passwordConfirmationForm" class="form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-valid-email ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern" novalidate="" name="passwordConfirmationForm">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="ng-bind-htmling" ng-bind-html="translation.login_email">Email</label>
<div class="input-group">
<span id="basic-addon1" class="input-group-addon">
    <input id="email" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid-email ng-valid-pattern ng-not-empty ng-valid ng-valid-required" type="email" required="" disabled="disabled" placeholder="Email" ng-model="confirm.Email" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/" name="email"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="ng-bind-htmling" ng-bind-html="model.PH_Password">Password</label>
<div class="input-group">
<span id="basic-addon1" class="input-group-addon">
    <input id="newPassword" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern" type="password" required="" placeholder="Password" ng-model="confirm.Password" name="password" ng-pattern="/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/"/>
</div>
<span class="ng-bind-htmling ng-hide" ng-bind-html="model.Error_Password" style="color:red" ng-show="passwordConfirmationForm.password.$invalid && submitted">Invalid Password Format (Ex : Admin123)</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="ng-bind-htmling" ng-bind-html="model.PH_RePassword">Confirm Password</label>
<div class="input-group">
<span id="basic-addon1" class="input-group-addon">
    <input id="rePassword" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-isolate-scope ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern" type="password" required="" placeholder="Confirm Password" data-password-verify="confirm.Password" ng-model="confirm.rePassword" name="rePassword" ng-pattern="/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/"/>
</div>
<span class="ng-bind-htmling ng-hide" ng-bind-html="model.Error_RePassword" style="color:red" ng-show="passwordConfirmationForm.rePassword.$invalid && submitted">Invalid Confirm Password.</span>
</div>    <div class="text-center"> </form>    </div>    </div>    </div>    </div>    </div>    </div>
```

**Selenium Code Here -**

```
@Test (priority=5,enabled=true)
  public void ConfirmationPw() throws Exception 
  {
      for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
          driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
          driver.navigate().refresh();

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("NewPassWordSet"))).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("password2"));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("ComfPassWordSet"))).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("password"));

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("PasswordConfirmationActiveButton"))).click(); 

    }
  }
```

**Popup new tab Image :-** [image]

Comment: If the test is flaky (i.e. works some times, and fails the other) one thing to consider is the async nature of the whole setup. Selenium will not wait for operation to complete to jump to the next step. Introducing a short wait or some step retry logic may help to get more stable performance, as browser might be in progress of loading the panel.

Comment: I added `Thread.sleep(9000);`  before this step run. but didn't work.

Comment: But did you see the tab appear on the screen of the selenium machine?

Comment: Yes. It is appears on the Screen and please check the screenshot i attached. Finally this code runs after this popup appears on the screen.

Comment: Hmm... did you add the waiting before the whole step, or after you switched to the window and refreshed?

Cause findElement call might be executing too soon. If it is sitll not working, you may try to use capability of the selenium driver to execute javascript in the browser to try to list elements by javascript within the browser.

Comment: This is the answer i found :- [answer]     `ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
   driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
  {
    driver.navigate().refresh();   
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("NewPassWordSet"))).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("password2"));  
  }`